# Java arrays formatting

Tags: java

I am nearly done with my project (technically it's finished), but I am having a big problem with little detail such as output formatting. I am fairly new to JAVA and would apreciatte any help you can provide.

I need to output 2 arrays (String and Int) in some sort of table format.
Example: 
England      4.6
USA          2.6
Japan        7.8
etc

I need exact spacing between the characters. I'll give you one part of my code: (I can apply the logic to the rest of the program)

```
    double beerStrenghts [] = new double [10];
    for(int x = 0; x < beerStrenghts.length; x++){
        beerStrenghts[x] = beerStrenghts()[x];
    }
    String beerName [] = new String [10];
    for(int x = 0; x < beerName.length; x++){
        beerName[x] = (beerName()[x]);
    }
    String lookup;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter search criteria. Min 3 characters.");
    lookup = keyboard.nextLine();
        while(lookup.length() < 3){
            System.out.println("Please enter at least 3 characters");
            lookup = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
    int indexInt;
    boolean found;
    for(int x = 0; x< beerName.length; x++){
            found = beerName[x].toUpperCase().contains(lookup.toUpperCase());
            if(found){
                fmt.format("%12s%3d",beerName[x], beerStrenghts[x]);
                System.out.println(fmt);
            }
    }

}

public static String [] beerName(){
String[] beerName = new String[10];
beerName[0] = "Heineken";
beerName[1] = "Bud Light";
beerName[2] = "Coors Light";
beerName[3] = "Leffe Blonde";
beerName[4] = "Budweiser";
beerName[5] = "Erdinger Non-Alcoholic";
beerName[6] = "Bud Premier Select";
beerName[7] = "Corona";
beerName[8] = "Barefoot Bohemian";
beerName[9] = "3 Monts"; 
return beerName;
}
public static double [] beerStrenghts(){
double beerStrenghts [] = new double [10];
beerStrenghts[0] = 4.0;
beerStrenghts[1] = 4.2;
beerStrenghts[2] = 4.3;
beerStrenghts[3] = 6.6;
beerStrenghts[4] = 5.0;
beerStrenghts[5] = 0.0;
beerStrenghts[6] = 7.4;
beerStrenghts[7] = 4.6;
beerStrenghts[8] = 4.0;
beerStrenghts[9] = 8.5;
return beerStrenghts;
```

Comment: What does you current output look like? and how exactly you want. Add some images maybe

Comment: This smells of a homework question...

Comment: Of course it's a homework question, but OP seems to have made a good-faith effort ... would be better if they said what specifically was wrong...

Comment: Why are you giving floating point values as an example if you want to output an integer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to (re)read the javadoc for [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). In particular, it says that the formatting code `d` is for decimal *integers*. You are dealing with doubles, so the `f` code is probably more your style. (I'm just guessing though since you've been very light on details.)

Try something like

```
fmt.format("%-12s%3.1f",beerName[x], beerStrenghts[x]);
```

Comment: %3.1f ?? That would just give 1decimal precision..coz he is using %3 that doesn't seem desirable

Comment: All of OP's beer strengths only had 1 digit after the decimal point. That's why I did `%3.1f`. `4.7` is 3 characters wide and 1 precision point. OP can easily adjust the precision and width if they want more space.

Comment: Agreed..i thought he wants 3 decimal points formatting..thus my answer has that :P

Answer (score 0):

just  change `%3d` to `%.03f`or `%.3f`
like :

```
fmt.format("%-12s %.03f", beerName[x], beerStrenghts[x]);
```

%d is used for formatting integers.

also have a look at StringBuilder if you want different locales i.e different ways of formatting for different regions.
More about formatters with string builders here:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for all help guys. And apologies for not providing enough details... I am also new in stack overflow.

This is my college project indeed (small part of it). Unfortunately majority of solutions-problems haven't being covered during classes - but I am doing my own researches(going very very well - almost done, formatting is the last part) and though I'll give my shoot here :)

Thanks for java.until.formatter reference dcsohl - I'll definitely go through it.

The solution given is almost working  but I cant figure out what is the problem this time.  Current output while searching for "bud":

Bud Light              4.2
Bud Light              4.2Budweiser              5.0
Bud Light              4.2Budweiser              5.0Bud Premier Select     7.4

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This looks like it belongs as an edit to your post. Look at the bottom left of your post for the `edit` button.